# Python Scipy RFFT Issue

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to run the following Python code, and get the error posted below the code snippet. I am using Scipy to try and plot a rfft of ADC samples, however, I get an error with this line of code:     fft_values = np.fft.rfft(data). When I try this line of code instead everything works:     fft_values = np.fft.fft(data)

From my understanding, fft() and rfft() accept the same function parameters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import wavfile
from scipy.signal import butter, sosfilt


# Define bandstop filter
def bandstop_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq
    sos = butter(order, [low, high], btype='bandstop', output='sos')
    y = sosfilt(sos, data)
    return y

# Main function
def main():
    # Read wave file
    sample_rate, data = wavfile.read('untitled16.wav')

    # Check if stereo
    if len(data.shape) > 1:
        # Average over the two channels
        data = np.mean(data, axis=1)

    # Apply bandstop filter
    ##filtered_signal = bandstop_filter(fft_values, -10, 10, sample_rate)

    # Compute FFT
    fft_values = np.fft.rfft(data)

    # Compute corresponding frequencies
    N = len(data)
    T = 1.0 / sample_rate
    xf = np.linspace(-1.0/(2.0 * T), 1.0/(2.0 * T), N)

    # Shift the FFT values so that the negative frequencies are on the left
    fft_values = np.fft.fftshift(fft_values)
    
    # Plot FFT
    plt.plot(xf, 1.0/N * np.abs(fft_values))
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**I get the following error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dlaroche/Desktop/Demodulation/WAVE_FFT.py", line 47, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/dlaroche/Desktop/Demodulation/WAVE_FFT.py", line 41, in main
    plt.plot(xf, 1.0/N * np.abs(fft_values))
  File "/home/dlaroche/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3575, in plot
    return gca().plot(
  File "/home/dlaroche/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1721, in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(self, *args, data=data, **kwargs)]
  File "/home/dlaroche/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 303, in __call__
    yield from self._plot_args(
  File "/home/dlaroche/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 499, in _plot_args
    raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (507915,) and (253958,)
```

Comment: Does this `rfft` docs line explain, `If n is even, the length of the transformed axis is (n/2)+1. If n is odd, the length is (n+1)/2.`.  `(507915+1)/2` is `253958`

Comment: When I change the code to the following:     plt.plot((xf+1)/2, fft_values)

I get the following error:     
raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (507915,) and (253958,)

Comment: You changed the `xf` values, not number of values.